# Utilizing the Different Parts of a String when Using the split() Method JAVA

Tags: java, split

I am looping through an ArrayList of Strings called **s** with this while loop.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < s.length()) {

  i++;
  s.get(i).split(",");

}
```

I am trying to `split()` each line of `s` using the delimiter `","`.
I want to put each part of each line into a new `Product` object like this:
`new Product(s.get(i) first part, s.get(i) second part)`.

I can't find a way to capture and utilize each part of the string that I am splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` method returns a string array.

Also, use a for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
    String[] parts = s.get(i).split(",");
    Product product = new Product(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] result = s.get(i).split(",");
```

`result` contains the individual split parts of the string.

and also in your while loop correct the length method to `s.length`, from `s.length()`